# Splitting the screens in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a requirement to split the screen into half and display the duplicate data on the other side of the screen. Initially this was achieved through a popup.

Hence user can compare the data without switching the screen. I want to avoid the use of iFrames for this. Could anyone guide me on how to get started with this. My application is pure Angular.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean split a page? Like a table on left and click row to show details on right? Question is very vague. Suggest you update with more specifics and some code

Comment: Yes split the page, and then display the content which was previously on the page. So the screen splits and displays the same content on both the sides of the screen but with different action buttons on the page.

Comment: So what specific issues are you having? Using a  service to share data between 2 controllers should make this relatively easy to get started with. Might even be able to use 2 instances of one controller

Comment: That I have figured out, I'm passing different variables to the scope and hence my controller can distinguish which side of the screen it is at. What I wanted to know was how do I split the screen into 2. There are various plugins out there, but I'm not interested in them.

Comment: not sure what makes that difficult, should be very simple css

Comment: kendo ui has an angular version of their splitter. I believe there's an open source version of their libs - http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/splitter/angular

Answer (score 3):

Pretty much most of what you're looking for is in this tutorial:

[AngularJS, Master-Detail page](http://mikesknowledgebase.azurewebsites.net/pages/Services/WebServices-Page8.7.htm)

It shows how to split the screen into two, and display a clickable list of items on the left, and an item's details on the right.  But for your request, it sounds like you'd want the same on both sides..?

[image]